# MVC framework and controls

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am new to web and MVC framework and have a few question on MVC F/W controls.

I used `@Html.EditorFor(model=>model.Date)` in my view and it always brings up a text box instead of a date picker.

If we choose **not** to use jQuery ui or any third party library, does dotnet MVC framework provide controls like date picker / datagrid or carousel controls?

I tried looking for these and seems like everyone points at jQuery/third-party controls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> does dotnet MVC framework provide controls like date picker / datagrid or carousel controls ?

Nope. But in ASP.NET MVC 4 you could decorate your view model property with the `DataType` attribute and it will generate an HTML 5 input of `type="date"`.

```
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
public DateTime Date { get; set; }
```

Modern browsers that support the `date` input field will handle it.

Comment: I am using firefox/IE and the output has type as "Date". But it still doesnot showup a datepicker.

Comment: That's probably because the browser you are using doesn't support it. Try with Google Chrome and you will see the datepicker.

Comment: Thanks !! it works on chrome. So to be on safer side, using a jquery like control is the only option ? or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: If you want to implement a cross browser datepicker, then yes, you have to use some of the existing client side frameworks such as jQuery UI.

Comment: Thanks a lot. You saved a lot of time for me.

Answer (score 2):

You just need include jqueryUI to add class to textBox

```
@Html.EditorFor(model=>model.Date, new {@class = "hasDatepicker"})
```

Comment: I know. But I am trying to avoid the Jquery like libraries for a change.

Comment: You cannot avoid. MVC framework does not have controls like WebForms